# Get image path after took it from camera in swift 4

Tags: ios, xcode, swift4

I have a button which shows the default camera screen in ios, When I take the photo, it saves in the phone and after that I want to get the

> UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL

because I want to send the photo to my server, When I trying to get the UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL the app crashes and get the error with nil value

This is my code:

```
@objc func take_photo(){
        if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.camera){
            let camera_picker = UIImagePickerController()
            camera_picker.delegate = self
            camera_picker.sourceType = .camera
            camera_picker.allowsEditing = false
            self.present(camera_picker, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }


func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
        if let img_original = info["UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"] as? UIImage{
            pickerImg_seleccionada = img_original
        }
        UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(pickerImg_seleccionada!, self, #selector(image(_:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:)), nil)
        if let img_seleccionada = pickerImg_seleccionada {
            img.display(image: img_seleccionada)
            img.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
            let imgData: NSData = NSData(data: UIImageJPEGRepresentation((pickerImg_seleccionada)!, 0.9)!)
            let imageSize: Int = imgData.length
            img_size = Double(imageSize) / (1024.0 * 1024.0)
            rep_imagen = UIImageJPEGRepresentation((pickerImg_seleccionada)!, 0.9)
            let url_imagen = info["UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL"] as! URL //here is the error
            image_name = url_imagen.lastPathComponent
        }

        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    @objc func image(_ image: UIImage, didFinishSavingWithError error: Error?, contextInfo: UnsafeRawPointer) {
        if let error = error {
            // we got back an error!
            print("no guardada")
        } else {
            print("guardada")
        }
    }
```

How can I solve that?, I think the process is good, because the image is stored and I can get the img_size and rep_imagen but not the url_imagen

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the user captures a photo using the image picker controller, there is no UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL key in the info dictionary. Nothing is saved to disk. The captured image is the UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage, which you already have. That’s all there is.

Comment: So, how can I get the path or What do i have to send to my server?

Comment: I don’t understand what you’re asking or what your goal is. You have the image data. No “path” is available or needed. You asked why you’re crashing and I told you why.